# "client denied by server configuration" after password protection setup in apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, password-protection

I created .htaccess and .htpassword for password protection in apache. Then, I modified `https.conf`.

```
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    #AllowOverride None
    AllowOverride AuthConfig All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

After the setting, password protection works fine, but the issue is that the webpage cannot load image file which is in subdirectory of "/Library/WebServer/Documents". Executing `tail /var/log/apache2/error_log` gives me this error message.

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Library/WebServer/Documents/moniwiki/data/cache/gnuplot/wikipagesetupMacBookProTask]-wikipages.png, referer: http://localhost/moniwiki/wiki.php/setupMacBookProTask
```

When I make `AllowOverride AuthConfig None`, the error is gone, then there is no password protection.

What's wrong with this? How can I access the subdirectory with password protection?

Comment: A subdirectory will have the same restrictions as its parent unless there is an overriding stanza in httpd.conf (or in a .htaccess file).  If /Library/WebServer/Documents already has correct password protection, try deleting any .htaccess or httpd.conf stanzas specific to the image directory and let it inherit from the parent directory.

Comment: @Lotharyx: There is no additional .htaccess or any more setup in https.conf other the one in /Library/WebServer/Documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the instruction on [this wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration), I added

```
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/moniwiki/data/cache/gnuplot">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

to the https.conf, and it works fine.